# Smartest way to handle "first click - show; second click hide"

Tags: jquery

I want to create buttons on my site that show windows using an animation when they're clicked the first time and hide that window using another animation when they're clicked the second time:

```
var aActivated = false;
var bActivated = false;
var cActivated = false;
....

$('#aButton').click(function() {
  if (aActivated)
    $('#myWindowA').animate( // ANIMATION THAT SHOWS WINDOW BY SLIDING TO THE LEFT // );
  else 
    $('#myWindowA').animate( // ANIMATION THAT HIDES WINDOW BY SLIDING TO THE RIGHT // );
  aActivated = !aActivated;
});

$('#bButton').click(function() { ........
```

My solution works but it means declaring a boolean for each button on the page and having to write an `if/else` statement for each click. It becomes messy with lots of buttons...

It's nothing too bad but I can't help thinking there must be a smarter way for me to do this. Of course if I was just using `slideToggle()` it would be less code but my animations are a bit more funky.

Comment: Couldn't you just set a data attribute on each element and then change/check as needed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [**data()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) instead of the globals, makes it a lot easier to attach event handlers to multiple elements :

```
$('.many_buttons').on('click', function() {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    if (flag) {
        $('#myWindowA').animate( ... );
    } else {
        $('#myWindowA').animate( ... );
    }

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5KB7/)